# Disambiguate [python-tesseract] and [pytesser]

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

PyTesser is an old project hosted on Google Code: https://code.google.com/archive/p/pytesser/

And here's a very old PyPI package, last updated in 2007: https://pypi.org/project/PyTesser/

(And an unrelated GitHub project: https://github.com/RobinDavid/Pytesser)

A cursory viewing shows that roughly half of these questions are mistagged since they actually have to do with [pytesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytesseract). So these questions need to be retagged and the tag wikis modified so people don't make the same mistake. But I'm not sure how to go about this.

Also worth mentioning that [tesserocr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tesserocr) should get its own tag: see [What is the difference between Pytesseract and Tesserocr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761638/what-is-the-difference-between-pytesseract-and-tesserocr)